# What does *array[] mean?

Tags: c++

What does this mean? I see it all the time in programs and I don't get it:

```
int *array[9];
```

Why is the asterisk there. What is the difference between this declaration and this:

```
int array[9];
```

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*arr%5B9%5D) and [The Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) are both good references.

Comment: did you just post [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13806/how-can-i-improve-this-program-c)? Twice `int *array[9]` within a few minutes looks like more than incidental...

Comment: @Philipp, That's someone else (trust me). I would imagine seeing that now was what sparked the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an array of pointers to an integer.  (array size is 9 elements.  Indexes: 0 - 8)

This can also be stated as being an array of integer pointers.

`int array[9]` , is an array of integers.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't really clear to me.  I'd say it's an array of integer pointers.

Answer (score 2):

an array of 9 pointers to int type

The asterisk means pointer. You can read the Backus-Naur form for C language to see the definitions of types.

Comment: Don't tell me you learn a programming language by reading its syntax' BNF.